# mCustomScrollbar not working for dropdown

Tags: jquery, scrollbar

[Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/uniEH) is the code what I have done so far.

I have tried calling the `$(".memberCnt").mCustomScrollbar();` in side the click event 
still its not working.

Can some one help me finding out the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were right in calling the `$(".memberCnt").mCustomScrollbar();` inside the click event.

just remove `height: 208px; overflow: auto;` of `.memberCnt ul` and apply it to `.memberCnt`

[Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LHAnz) is the updated code